# Doing operations down columns in R, indexing by another column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, finance

I am trying to compute the hedging error for an options pricing model. Each day, I will compute an equivalent position that one should take when hedging against this option in the market, let's call it X_s, and compute the cash position of the hedge, let's call it X_0, for every given day. This doesn't present any issues since I can mapply() a function that calculates all the necessary partials given my parameters, stock price, etc. to compute X_s and X_0. Where I am starting to run into issues is when trying to compute the hedging error for my models. Here's a subset of my data that I'm looking at:

```
       date  optionid px_last           r X_s_position     X_0_cash  mp_ba
1 2020-03-03 127117475 3003.37 0.011587702  0.642588548 -1783.881169 146.05
2 2020-03-03 131373646 3003.37 0.011587702  0.527107056 -1477.947518 105.15
3 2020-03-06 127117475 2972.37 0.008128021  0.566540143 -1558.566925 125.40
4 2020-03-09 127117475 2746.56 0.004745339  0.133284145  -332.122900  33.95
5 2020-03-10 127117475 2882.23 0.005884274  0.413389283 -1125.632994  65.85
6 2020-03-11 127117475 2741.38 0.006223502  0.131700734  -333.691757  27.35
7 2020-03-12 127117475 2480.64 0.003787032  0.003680431    -8.179825   0.95
```

So, let's say we're looking at optionid == 127117475. On the first observation date we won't have any hedge error, so we go to the next observation on 2020-03-06. The hedge error on that day would be

```
0.642588548*2972.37 + -1783.881169*exp(0.011587702*as.numeric(2020-03-06 - 2020-03-03)/365) - 105.15
```

So in row 3, in the new 'hedge error' column I want to create, the value would be 20.80985. So, to calculate the hedge error for the next observation of optionid == 127117475, I take the previous observation X_s_position multiply it by the next spot price (px_last), add the X_0_cash value multiplied by exp(r*(difference in days between the two observations)/365) and then subtract the next observation of the option price (mp_ba)

Comment: Help us help you! Please include some same data in the form of code we can run, and some expected output.

Comment: @JonSpring hi, I added a subsetted matrix of what I am looking at. I'm not sure how to upload any of the data very well to StackOverflow. I am a newer to coding.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like so? Should the `mp_ba` in your example be 125.40?

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(optionid) %>%
  mutate(hedge_error = lag(X_s_position)*px_last + X_0_cash*exp(lag(r)*as.numeric(date - lag(date))/365) - mp_ba)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 7 × 8
# Groups:   optionid [2]
  date        optionid px_last       r X_s_position X_0_cash  mp_ba hedge_error
  <date>         <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>        <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl>
1 2020-03-03 127117475   3003. 0.0116       0.643   -1784.   146.           NA 
2 2020-03-03 131373646   3003. 0.0116       0.527   -1478.   105.           NA 
3 2020-03-06 127117475   2972. 0.00813      0.567   -1559.   125.          226.
4 2020-03-09 127117475   2747. 0.00475      0.133    -332.    34.0        1190.
5 2020-03-10 127117475   2882. 0.00588      0.413   -1126.    65.8        -807.
6 2020-03-11 127117475   2741. 0.00622      0.132    -334.    27.4         772.
7 2020-03-12 127117475   2481. 0.00379      0.00368    -8.18   0.95        318.
```

Comment: Hi, yes that was my mistake when copying and pasting from the dataframe. Thank you so much for your help!